# What types of 'realism' questions are allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

I believe most of the movies and TV shows(99%) are imaginary and virtual. They can be having realistic story. But some scenes are not believable. They are not much realistic. Most of the movie and TV shows can be questioned under [realism](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/realism).

What are guidelines for asking question on [realism](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/realism)? What types of [realism](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/realism) questions are allowed?

Comment: I think the pre-existing questions on the tag are pretty good evidence.  Do you have a specific question or set of questions in mind?

Comment: @DForck42: About Real story questions, Movie techniques in sound, voice, scene capturing, reality in scenes, roles in TV show or movie?

Comment: i'm not sure i follow

Comment: Like *DForck42* I cannot really follow you. While in your question it sounds like you're speaking of questions regarding the realism of certain scenes or incidents (which I for myself would rather frown upon, being on the same line as plot-hole questions, though they can also be asked well), while your comment sounds much broader and more about filming techniques, or rather the real-life aspects of making movies. Those are too totally different topics (and can exhibit an equally broad range of question qualities and on-topicnesses). So what really is it you mean with the word *"realism"*?

Comment: @ChristianRau: You explained what I mean. I don't know what actually [tag:realism] mean? And when to use?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure what *"realism"* alludes to in this context, but it's a vague term that's going to apply to questions all over the map (see the questions using [that tag](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/realism) now).

Questions tagged [realism](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/realism) are probably better suited to one of the legitimate subjects of film study like [plot-inconsistency] or perhaps [suspension-of-disbelief]. I would try and get rid of this tag all together. I'm not sure the term *"realism"* is going to elicit a useful categorization of content, in this context.